# how to edit values of all TR of a table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code and would like to change the value of the input and when I edit the **TR** values would change automatically.

```js
$('.change').change(function() { 
        var element = $(this).parent();
        console.log('get result: ' + $(this).parent().find('.resultt').val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
        <tr>
            <td> ASDADAS </td>
            <td> 2 </td>
            <td> 2017-08-21 </td>
            <td class='money'> 130.00 </td>
            <td> <input type='text' class='change' style='width: 30%;' value='0.033%'  /> </td>
            <td class='resultt'> 130.04 </td>
            <td class='parcial'> 0.04 </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
        <tr>
            <td> XXFDFD </td>
            <td> 1 </td>
            <td> 2017-08-20 </td>
            <td class='money'> 121.34 </td>
            <td> <input type='text' class='change' style='width: 30%;' value='0.033%'  /> </td>
            <td class='resultt'> 120.36 </td>
            <td class='parcial'> 0.34 </td>
        </tr>
    </form>                                
</tbody>
```

I tried using the script to see if I could get the value of the **CLASS** so I could edit it. But I have not been successful.

Comment: `console.log('get result: ' + $(this).closest('tr').find('.resultt').text());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$(this).closest('tr').find('.resultt').text()`

`td` will give you `text()` and not `val()`

```js
$('.change').change(function() {
  var element = $(this).parent();

  console.log('get result: ' + $(this).closest('tr').find('.resultt').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
      <tr>
        <td> ASDADAS </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 2017-08-21 </td>
        <td class='money'> 130.00 </td>
        <td> <input type='text' class='change' style='width: 30%;' value='0.033%' /> </td>
        <td class='resultt'> 130.04 </td>
        <td class='parcial'> 0.04 </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
      <tr>
        <td> XXFDFD </td>
        <td> 1 </td>
        <td> 2017-08-20 </td>
        <td class='money'> 121.34 </td>
        <td> <input type='text' class='change' style='width: 30%;' value='0.033%' /> </td>
        <td class='resultt'> 120.36 </td>
        <td class='parcial'> 0.34 </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </tbody>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent of the input is the cell, not the row. Try calling parent twice, or even better try using `.closest("tr")`.